# How to persist selected range in Infragistics WebMonthCalendar control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, infragistics

I have implemented context menu in Infragistics WebMonthCalendar for marking holidays on selected date. It is working fine when user select single date. I have set selection type to "multi", but when user selects a range and then right click it clears the selection range and selects a single date. Is there any way to persist range selection on right click?
Any suggestion in this regards is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the MouseDown client side event of the WebMonthCalendar and set cancel to true to retain the selection.  I posted an example [here](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/66898/359629.aspx#359629).